# Перегрузка операторов ввода/вывода при наследовании

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, перегрузка-операторов, дружественная-функция

Есть базовый класс Computer и производный класс Laptop:

```
class Computer
{
private:
    string model;
};

class Laptop : Computer
{
private:
    string typeOfLaptop;
};
```

Каким образом следует перегрузить операторы ввода/вывода?
Я могу сделать это задав параметры базового класса типом protected и реализовать дружественные функции.

```
class Computer
{
protected:
    string model;
};

class Laptop : public Computer
{
private:
    string typeOfLaptop;

public:
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Laptop& obj);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Laptop& obj);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Laptop& obj)
{
    in >> obj.model >> obj.typeOfLaptop;
    return in;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Laptop& obj)
{
    return os << obj.model << " " << obj.typeOfLaptop;
}
```

Но я думаю, что это не совсем верно. Может быть есть способ получше?

Comment: это абсолютно верно.

Comment: Если `Computer` не абстрактный класс, то у него должны быть свои `operator>>`  и `operator<<`.

Comment: Плохой способ, если речь идет о наборе производных классов, так как для использования этих классов вам нужно знать тип выводимого объекта. Чтобы этого избежать нужно определить оператор вывода для базового класса, который обращается к виртуальному методу класса, который принимает поток в качкстве аргумента. Этот способ похож на использование визитера и очень хорош тем, что нет необходимости знать тип объекта перед его выводом

Comment: А если класс абстрактный, то использования protected всё таки лучший выход?

Comment: Как любит говорить господин  Страуструп: "Лучшего способа не бывает".  В одном случаи лучше так, в другом по другому, но все равно кто то предложит вариант по лучше с какой то точки зрения